# How to create liste filter in sonata admin bundle

Tags: filter, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

What's the equivalent for the following function, but for `datagridFilters` in sonata admin bundle?

```
->add('users', 'entity', array(
'class' => 'AcmeHelloBundle:User',
'property' => 'username',

));
```

Comment: Please add some information from your entities, it will help.

Comment: I created an entity employee who has the following properties: 
- name 
- first names 
- address

I would like to create a filter search by property name. it must be a select-box filled with the names of the employees in the database with autocomplete option if possible

Comment: Found an answer @user3451193 ? Normally you use something like `doctrine_orm_choice` as  second parameter and the first one links to your admin name e.g. `employee`. An Autocomplete version is on the way for large datasets: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/2360#issuecomment-60606620